# I need help arranging my Table View alphabetically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

Im trying to use this code:

```
sortedArray = [anArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Should I put this in my viewDidLoad? I am using an NSMutableArray to populate the table.

Answer (score 0):

You should use it as the datasource of your tableview. And return the objects at the indexes in the delegate methods.

Once sorted then reload the tableview.

Comment: I came across another line of code that seems more appropriate NSSortDescriptor *sortParam= [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[yourArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortParam]];

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting these values from an api call to a server. If like that just before you call the reload function after the api call sort the array.

Comment: I must be using the wrong code then because that’s not what I’m trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to sort the elements either before the first request to get the data from your `UITableViewDataSource` or when the data is loaded into the `NSMutableArray`.  If your data is loaded in your `viewDidLoad:`, then just do the sort immediately after loading the data and you'll be able to respond to the `NSTableViewDataSource` requests with the items in the array and they'll be sorted.

If the items arrive slowly, you might want to delay the sort, so that you aren't doing too many sort operations, but basically perform it when you tell the NSTableView that new data has arrived.   So, if you're receiving data from a server, for example (which you stated you were not), you could do this after receiving another batch of entries.

Have you implemented your UITableViewDataSource methods yet?

Comment: I found another way to sort the data using this code in my viewDidLoad NSSortDescriptor *sortParam= [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"treeName" ascending:YES];
    [ds sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortParam]]; Everything works fine however all strings containing letter i are at the end for some reason

Comment: Sounds like it might be a case insensitivity issue.  Try using `[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"treeName" ascending: YES selector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]` to make the comparison case insensitive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used your code and ended up with this NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"treeName" ascending: YES selector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
     [ds sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]]; I understand now that my problem was that I wasn't using case insensitive.